# After deleting altervista's .htaccess, the site keeps redirecting me to the old URL

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I uploaded Laravel on altervista and set the .htaccess to redirect all requests to public/index.php. Now I have deleted all files (including .htaccess) and created a simple index.html file in the / folder, but when I visit the site it keeps redirecting me to the old public/index.php path.
Is this a problem that I can resolve or do I have to ask the altervista's team?

Comment: Could it be that you are looking at a cache redirection result in your browser? Have a try using a fresh anonymous browser window.

Comment: Yes, I tried using Firefox and it worked. However I don't know how to delete chrome's cache or how to stop it from caching these information.

Comment: You probably had implemented a `R=301` redirection in your old setup, that is a _permanent_ redirection. The purpose is that the client does _not_ have to check again for each request, but can assume the redirection is still in place because it is cached. That is what _permanent_ means. You cannot "undo" that, you can only wait for the cache to expire or manually clear the browser cache (in the settings). There are other possibilities, but from the minimal details you gave in your question that is my guess.

Answer (score 0):

depending on how your host is set up your document root may be `public/`. Try and move `public/index.php` to `public/index.backup` and place your new `index.html` in the public folder and see if you can access it.

If this works and you want your document root to be `/` and not `public/` you likely will have to talk with your provider